# Change width of legend indicator color in google chart

Tags: css, charts, google-visualization, styles

I need to make smaller (less width) the legend indicator color at right side but i dont know how if it's possible.

[image: My chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there aren't any options to control the width of the legend indicators
(that I can find)

and I'm not sure how you would accomplish with css,
since the same element types used to draw the chart,
are used to draw the legend

you can, however, modify manually with script,
once the chart's `'ready'` event fires

the hard part is identifying which elements to change

following is one option,
but requires a *continuous* x-axis (`'number'`), vs. *discrete* (`'string'`)

this would allow you to use chart method `getXLocation`,
to find elements outside of the chart area

see following working snippet,
the width of the indicators is reduced by half...

note: reducing the width of the color indicators will not move the text labels
those will need to be manually moved as well...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'Geotermia', 'Mareomotriz y Undimotriz'],
    [2015, 100, 200],
    [2020, 110, 215],
    [2025, 130, 225],
    [2030, 140, 230],
    [2035, 160, 250],
    [2040, 180, 260],
    [2045, 190, 276],
    [2050, 195, 300]
  ]);

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(container);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // get max x coordinate of the chart area
    var browserIsIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var xRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
    var xMax = chartLayout.getXLocation(xRange.max);
    var reducedWidth = 0;

    // look for non-text elements outside the chart area
    $('#chart_div path, #chart_div rect').each(function (index, element) {
      var bounds;
      var path;
      var pathPoint;
      var xCoord;

      switch ($(element).prop('tagName')) {
        case 'rect':
          // change width
          xCoord = parseFloat($(element).attr('x'));
          if ((xCoord > xMax) && ($(element).attr('fill') !== '#ffffff')) {
            reducedWidth = parseFloat($(element).attr('width')) / 2;
            $(element).attr('width', reducedWidth);
          }
          break;

        case 'path':
          // change path
          bounds = element.getBBox();
          if (bounds.x > xMax) {
            reducedWidth = (bounds.width / 2);
            if (browserIsIE) {
              path = $(element).attr('d').split(' ');
              path[4] = parseFloat(path[1]) + reducedWidth;
              path = path.join(' ');
              $(element).attr('d', path);
            } else {
              path = $(element).attr('d').split(',');
              pathPoint = path[1].split('L');
              path = path[0] + ',' + pathPoint[0] + 'L' + (bounds.x + reducedWidth) + ',' + path[2];
              $(element).attr('d', path);
            }
          }
          break;
      }
    });

    // look for text elements outside the chart area
    $('#chart_div text').each(function (index, element) {
      var bounds;
      var xCoord;

      // change x coord
      bounds = element.getBBox();
      if (bounds.x > xMax) {
        xCoord = parseFloat($(element).attr('x')) - (reducedWidth) + 4;
        $(element).attr('x', xCoord);
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, {
    chartArea: {
      bottom: 48,
      height: '100%',
      left: 48,
      right: 200,
      top: 24,
      width: '100%'
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: '0000',
      ticks: [
        2015,
        2020,
        2025,
        2030,
        2035,
        2040,
        2045,
        2050
      ]
    },
    height: '100%',
    isStacked: true,
    title: 'TWh',
    width: '100%'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: I really like your answer but i think something is bad cause it throw an error in the snippet :/

Comment: Nice!, but what about FF? im using it and still no working.
I saw it in Chrome and looks great!

Comment: and there's probably a better way to parse the path's d attribute on SO somewhere...

Comment: Thanks a lot! it's what im looking for.

Comment: After trying to implement this answer i get an issue. I think when the text labels are to long they place in the wrong way, try to check it with this two and you will see.
"Geotermia",
"Mareomotriz y Undimotriz"

Comment: Is not the option of right area, i tried it already. Im not sure about how to fix it.

Comment: changed answer above, there was a problem with the logic for `<text>` elements...